# Delete your own question

Tags: discussion

I recently posted a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1093469/what-is-the-significance-of-the-output-of-sudo-cat-etc-group) on [Askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com), I realized later that its answer is obvious and only needs to read the man page of a command.
Now I am not sure whether to delete it or let it or just close it.

Comment: You should be able to see a "delete" button yourself.  But I'll delete your question if you *really* want it deleted...

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After reviewing your question, what's obvious to you is not obvious to newbies who might be digging.

I'm not going to delete your question because it could have value to users looking for information such as that which you asked about.  Even the 'stupid' questions sometimes have value!

Typically, if you wanted to delete your own post though, users should see a delete button underneath their answer they can use (unless it's answered):

[image]

If the question has an answer, though, and that answer is accepted or upvoted you might not be able to do this, so you'd need to flag the question for moderator attention to request deletion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what made me confused about my question is that ''may be if I delete it because it is *obvious* for some of the community members, it would not be necessarily obvious for  another some of the community members''. 
Thank you.

Comment: @singrium I added additional info for where you can find the delete button ffor the future (you won't see 'mod' obviously but...)  However, it's still a good question despite the 'some people may know this already', so it's fine to keep it :)

Comment: Thank you for your cooperation, **long live the community** :)